# APScheduler raise TypeError('func must be callable') TypeError: func must be callable

Tags: python, json, apscheduler

When i try to run Below code it gives following error and unable to call myDialerJob function.

"raise ValueError('Not adding job since it would never be run')"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort,json, redirect, url_for
from apscheduler.job import Job
from apscheduler.jobstores.shelve_store import ShelveJobStore
from apscheduler.jobstores.redis_store import RedisJobStore
import redis
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
sched = Scheduler()
sched.add_jobstore(RedisJobStore(), 'redisJobStore')
app = Flask(__name__)
def myDialerJob(campaignID):
     print "Running sceduled Job NO: %s " % campaignID
     return
@app.route('/campaignNow', methods = ['POST'])
def create_task_now():
        if not request.json or not 'campaignId' in request.json:
                abort(400)
        execTime = datetime.now()
        job = sched.add_date_job(myDialerJob, execTime, args=[request.json['campaignId']], jobstore='redisJobStore')
        resp = jsonify({ 'status': 'Campaign started!' })
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp
if __name__ == '__main__':
        sched.start()
        app.run(debug = True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

But when i change a part of function create_task_now().

```
  job = sched.add_date_job(myDialerJob(request.json(request.json['campaignId']), execTime, args=[request.json['campaignId']], jobstore='redisJobStore')
```

It is able to call the function myDialerJob but at the end it gives following error.
      raise TypeError('func must be callable')
      TypeError: func must be callable

The only difference is calling the function with a value.

Same code was working perfectly before.

Your Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Calling the function causes the return value of that function to be passed as an argument to `add_date_job`. The function doesn't return anything, so you're effectively doing `job = sched.add_date_job(None, execTime, args=[request.json['campaignId']], jobstore='redisJobStore')`

Comment: As for the first problem, it may be that `datetime.now()` is already in the past by the time the scheduling is checked. You could try to add a few seconds to that or see if there is a different call to do a one-time job immediately.